# Javacard - UICC - SMS-PP Data Download envelope returns always 9000

Tags: sms, smartcard, javacard, apdu, sim-card

I tried to send a SMS with APDU (without the 23.048 headers - I know it doesn't suppose to be without those headers).

For every SMS (no matter what the APDU I sent) I got the 9000 response (no additional data even if setting the Le byte).

Can someone please explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Could you please add more details? What APDU? What applet should receive your APDU?

Comment: The APDU I sent is a SMS-PP Data Download envelope but without the 23.048 headers.                                                                      [envelope command][device id][address tlv][sms tpdu].                          I don't include the sms command headers - spi, kic, kid, tar and etc.                                                                                                               The selected applet is the USIM applet.

Comment: If you looking for help about the APDU messages content to ensure format you need to add your APDU messages example. Add your command/response traces.

Comment: I got an answer from the Global Platform mailing list. Appearently if no applet register to the triggered event the UICC will not raise an error (as I expected). Thank you for yoir time!

Comment: @Bluestar Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

So I got the answer from the GlobalPlatform mailing list -
For any event in the UICC, the card will trigger all the applets registered to the event or the applet specified by the TAR. If no applet registered to the event the UICC will act as the process done successfully - because no error or unpredictable behavior occurred.